# Wess-Zumino model: simplified vs non-simplified?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, terminology, field-theory, supersymmetry

According to [Ryder Quantum Field Theory](https://books.google.com.ar/books/about/Quantum_Field_Theory.html?id=nnuW_kVJ500C&redir_esc=y) page 440 the "simplified [Wess-Zumino model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wess%E2%80%93Zumino_model)" has the lagrangian 
$$ \mathscr{L} = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu A)^2 + \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu B)^2 + \frac{1}{4} \bar{\Psi} i \gamma^\mu \overleftrightarrow{\partial}_\mu \Psi .\tag{11.92}$$
After some calculations Ryder has the necessity to introduce two other auxiliary fields $F$ and $G$ (page 448) so that the "final lagrangian" is 
$$ \mathscr{L} = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu A)^2 + \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu B)^2 + \frac{1}{4} \bar{\Psi} i \gamma^\mu \overleftrightarrow{\partial}_\mu \Psi + \frac{1}{2}F^2 + \frac{1}{2} G^2 .\tag{11.144}$$
My question is: is this lagrangian with the four scalar fields the Wess-Zumino model? Or it is still the "simplified one"?

I could not find in Google the "simplified model" and the "posta model" (the term "posta" means the real one, it is a word we use very often in my country).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The models (11.144) & (11.92) are called the *free massless Wess-Zumino model with or without auxiliary fields,* respectively. The point being that the SUSY algebra is realized off-shell and only on-shell, respectively. The word *simplified* seems to be non-standard terminology by Ryder.

Comment: Thanks! So I think that the "non-simplified model" is the one with mass and/or interactions.